# Accessing to fields in FormGroup issue

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In my angular 4 application I want to show error message under the field if the field is required and if some pattern is not respected.

But I have a problem when I am in a formgroup, in my case I am inside the first step of a `mat-stepper` and when I try to see if there are some error using `.hasError('pattern')` I have this error:

> ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_4(...).hasError is not a function
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

This is the html:

```
    <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" class="custom-stepper">
        <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Primo step</ng-template>

       <mat-form-field> <input matInput rebusFocus
        formControlName="licensePlate" #licensePlate
         (keyup)="searchLicensePlate(licensePlate.value, $event)" placeholder="{{'ticket.new.labels.licenseplate' | translate }}"
            [matAutocomplete]="licensePlateAuto" name="licensePlate">
            <mat-icon matSuffix>directions_car</mat-icon> </mat-form-field>
            <mat-autocomplete #licensePlateAuto="matAutocomplete"
             (change)="setLicensePlate(licensePlate)"> <mat-option
                *ngFor="let licensePlate of licensePlates"
                [value]="licensePlate.licensePlate">
                <div class="row">
                  <span>{{licensePlate.licensePlate}}</span>
                </div>
            </mat-option> </mat-autocomplete>

                <small *ngIf="licensePlate.hasError('pattern')"
                    class="text-danger">{{
                        'form.validation.licenseplatepattern' | translate }}</small>
```

And in my .ts:

```
firstFormGroup: FormGroup;

this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      licensePlate: ['', [Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9]{4,8}$')]],
      engineType: [''],
      engine: ['', [Validators.pattern('^[0-6]{1}$')]],
      particulatedFilter: [],
      miniBus: [],
      area: [],
      hotel: []
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
[ngClass]="{
   'invalid': licensePlate.invalid && (licensePlate.dirty || licensePlate.touched),
   'valid': licensePlate.valid && (licensePlate.dirty || licensePlate.touched)
 }">
```

and:

```
*ngIf="licensePlate.errors.hasOwnProperty(pattern)"
```

or just:

```
*ngIf="licensePlate.errors"
```

I hope it helps